# stackoverflow EN o ES

Tags: discusión, meta

Soy nuevo en la comunidad, y al principio pensé que al existir dos sitios diferentes había suficiente cantidad de personas como para que funcionaran bien separados, pero hoy me di cuenta tras esperar 2 días por una respuesta en stackoverflow en español solo obtuve 15 vista, 0 votos y mucho menos una respuesta, decidí publicar exactamente la misma pregunta en stackoverflow en inglés y en menos de 4 minutos obtuve una respuesta.

Lo anterior me hace pensar:

¿No será mejor para la comunidad unir todos los usuarios en stackoverflow en inglés?, ya que aun existen preguntas sin respuestas a pesar de pasar varios días, semanas o incluso meses.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la votacion en meta es distinta a la votacion del sitio principal. aca los votos significan de acuerdo o no de acuerdo. y no impactan tu reputacion. es solo una medida para saber que tan de acuerdo se esta con algo.

Comment: lo malo del sitio en español, es que la gente, o admins, o alguien, se dedica mas a ver la ortografia o si le parece o no la pregunta y respuesta. Tu pregunta es un ejemplo, alguien que empieza a usar el sitio empieza teniendo negativos, y listo decide alejarse gracias a los super usuarios que pueden darse el lujo de ponerte negativo por que no les parece algo.

Answer (score 11):

Estas confundiendo algo.

SO en español nacio hace 2 años.

SO en ingles tiene mas de 9 años, y se usa en todo el mundo.

SO en español, se usa solamente en sitios de habla hispana, y su carga de usuarios es mucho mas baja.

El problema que veo aca, es que no sabes como funciona la red. No hay que unir usuarios de ningun tipo, yo por ejemplo tengo usuario en los dos sitios, y el de SO en ingles tiene 9 años.

SO en español es un sitio nuevo y en crecimiento. Puede que tu pregunta haya caido en un mal horario (suele pasar) o que directamente nadie supiera la respuesta. Ahora, si obtuviste una respuesta en ingles, seria genial que tambien publicaras la solución a tu problema en la pregunta que hiciste.

No es necesario unir los dos sitios, ya que podes ir al sitio que mas te guste. Abrir un sitio en español (asi como uno en ruso, uno en portugues y uno en japones) fue una decisión de la comunidad de programadores en cada idioma, dentro de la comunidad de SO eng.

La red funciona con sitios, y cada sitio se maneja separado, asi que solo quedate con el sitio que mas te guste. Nada impide que hagas la pregunta en los dos sitios, y pases la respuesta cuando la consigas. Esto es algo que se puede hacer sin problemas (y que por ejemplo yo, hice alguna vez con alguna pregunta muy rebuscada).

Comment: y tambien agregaria que trabajamos en conjuntos con otros sitios para ir mejorando, en efecto si quieres ayudar a que nuestra comunidad de habla hispana siga creciendo, vamos eres bienvenido y ayudanos a responder mas preguntas

Answer (score 11):

No creo que lo que propones sea viable. No tiene sentido unir las dos comunidades porque son dos entidades diferentes con un mismo objetivo pero un público diferente. En ese sentido creo que estás comparando dos cosas que se parecen pero que no son lo mismo.

Creo que el argumento que propones tiene algunos puntos que son debatibles:

- Que haya preguntas sin respuesta después de días, semanas, o meses (o incluso años) es normal y también ocurre en el sitio en inglés. Aunque todo sea dicho, la cantidad de preguntas no respondidas (38%) es mayor que en el sitio en inglés (29%). Pero la menor cantidad de preguntas aquí va a impactar más porcentualmente.
- Que se responda más rápido allá es normal porque tienen 100 veces más usuarios que aquí (10 millones vs 100 mil). La probabilidad de que haya algún usuario disponible en un momento dado es mucho mayor allí que aquí.
- El uso de un sitio no implica el no-uso del otro. Por ejemplo, yo participo en diferentes comunidades de Stack Exchange y escribo preguntas y respuestas tanto en Stack Overflow en español como en inglés. En muchas ocasiones recibo respuesta en inglés antes que en español, en cuyo caso, la traduzco y la publicó en español (siempre poniendo referencia a la respuesta en inglés).

Y luego deberías plantearte una pregunta: **¿Cómo funcionaría tu propuesta para los desarrolladores que no sepan comunicarse en inglés?** Ten en cuenta que la comunidad de desarrolladores hispanos es muy grande y no todos hablan en inglés.  Les estaría cerrando una puerta importante al conocimiento.

---

Ahora, que no esté de acuerdo con tu propuesta, no quiere decir que no debamos hacer introspección y revisar lo que sugieres y nuestros métodos. El porcentaje de preguntas sin respuesta (38%) es uno de los más altos de la red de Stack Exchange. Eso debería hacernos reflexionar y buscar soluciones para ello... pero quizás eso sea más el tema para otra pregunta en meta.

Comment: opino lo mimo que tu @Alvaro Montoro, yo simpre he dicho que estos dos sitios on diferentes obviamente en el sitio  en ingles es mayor la gente obviamente porque esta activo desde hace 10 años y este no muho(nose exactamente cuanto tiempo pero tiene poco tiempo) yo creo que deberiamos crear la misma cultura de ellos pero obivamente adaptada a nosotros, mencionando lo del ingles creo yo(punto personal) todo los desarrolladores deberian estudiar o tener un B2 en ingles almenos osea yo en este momento sigo estudiando ingles pero ps yo siempre dijo con que encuentres tu respuesta ps TDF :p

Answer (score 7):

Te comentaré mi punto de vista personal,

Aunque SO en español actualmente tienen menos usuarios comparado con SO en inglés, dos motivos principales es que tenemos pocos años comparados con el sitio en inglés que tiene alrededor de 10 años y además esta dirigido a desarrolladores de habla hispana.

**Considerando lo que propones que es unir todos los usuarios a stackoverflow en inglés, recuerda que hay usuarios que tal vez no conocemos el idioma inglés o que no podemos expresarnos con fluidez, por lo tanto el uso de SO en español es esencial!.**

---

Algo muy importante, te comento que para tener éxito en el sitio es importante realizar tus preguntas en base a

[**¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Recuerda que esto potencializa tus oportunidades de obtener una respuesta, te lo comento porque he revisado algunas de tus publicaciones.

**Estamos creciendo y te aseguro que con el tiempo tendremos una base datos tanto de usuarios como de información que será de gran ayuda.**  Hay que contribuir con contenido de calidad y apoyando a nuevos usuarios a que contribuyan de buena manera en el sitio.

Answer (score 5):

La idea de **[es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)** es ayudar a personas de habla hispana a solventar problemas que probablemente no dominen bien el ingles o incluso ni lo hablen , de hecho, existen otros sitios como el [Ruso](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) y  el [Japones](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) para nombrarte alguno cada uno ayuda a personas de su idioma materno.

En base a lo que te comentaron unos de los [moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) y [@gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3812/28035) , puedes ver [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-traffic) y  sacar  tus conclusiones :

**StackOverFLow**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**es.StackOverFlow**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observa cada uno de los items  la diferencia abismal que hay, ten en cuenta que nosotros tenemos solo 3 Años (en realidad es menos por el modo Beta) y hemos crecido exponencialmente.

Para finalizar, si bien no lograste que te respondiéramos la pregunta satisfactoriamente, responde tu mismo marcala cerrada y te invito a ayudarnos a seguir creciendo,  generando respuesta de calidad a todos nuestros usuarios  y que el idioma no sea una barrera para aprender(ya que el contenido generalmente esta en ingles)

Answer (score 2):

Te comprendo sin embargo te comento lo siguiente:

1. Las métricas indican mucho, la cantidad de usuarios en la versión inglesa
2. La cantidad de usuarios activos, respondiendo y votando aquí es mucho menor
3. En la versión inglesa se responde mucho, pero en ocasiones no siempre son las mejores respuestas; algunas de ellas son solo comentarios y aún así son calificadas como respuestas
4. En SO en español se exige una mayor calidad en las aportaciones

El último punto, puede hacer también que la cantidad de respuestas, por que mientras en SO en inglés al ser cientos de miles de usuarios los reportes no se tratan a tiempo; en SO en español los reportes de comentarios en zona de respuestas se atienden en menos de 3 o 2 días (experiencia personal)

De modo que si no recibiste respuesta tal vez sea por:

1. No había usuarios logueados y con conocimiento de tu pregunta
2. Los usuarios al momento que estaban en la red, no tienen conocimiento de tu pregunta en especifico

Yo por ejemplo respondo mucho sobre:

1. PHP (algunas no todas)
2. Laravel (algunas no todas)

Pero no de ningún otro framework por que no los se usar

Entonces debes tener en cuenta que la comunidad al ser mucho mas pequeña es mas complejo encontrar respuesta rápida