# ¿Bug en contador de votos diarios en meta?

Tags: bug

El día de ayer por la noche dediqué algún tiempo a ponerme al día de los temas que se han tratado en los últimos meses en meta, por lo que emití una cantidad inusual de votos.

De esta manera, aparentemente alcancé el límite diario de votos (que son 40). Hoy por la mañana sigo en el tope, según he podido comprobar al intentar votar por [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3812/21), pero mi actividad muestra que no he emitido más que 37 votos.

[image: Estoy al límite de votos diario]

Anoche, al llegar a 30 votos, obtuve la medalla *sufragio*, pero **no llegué a obtener la medalla *vox populi***, pues en ese contador, dice que tengo **37 de 40 votos** en el día, cosa que he verificado que sigue igual hoy por la mañana

[image: El seguimiento de medallas cuenta solo 37/40]

¿Es esto un bug o hay algo que no estoy entendiendo bien sobre el funcionamiento del sitio?

**Edición**

Según puedo ver, al revisar mi actividad, luego del comentario de @Pikoh, efectivamente he emitido 37 votos en el día. Lo que deja como sospechoso, por ahora, al cálculo de los votos emitidos que se realiza para validar aplicar el límite a la hora de querer emitir un nuevo voto.

Comment: La verdad es que aparentemente tienes razón, podría ser un bug. Teniendo en cuenta que en todo el año 2018 no se ha concedido ninguna medalla vox populi en el sitio, y que no suele ser habitual que en meta se llegue a 40 votos en un dia, podría perfectamente haber pasado desapercibido...es complicado saberlo, ya que al ser votaciones no podemos revisar tu actividad...

Comment: Luego de tu comentario, he revisado mi actividad y edité la pregunta, pues me muestra 37 votos, pero sigue sin dejarme emitir más.

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso...creo que hay dos limites de votos diarios, uno general y otro para respuestas. Es posible que alcanzaras el limite diario de votos en respuestas (que son 30) pero no llegaras al de posts (que son 40). En ese caso, el problema es que debías haber votado 3 preguntas mas para ganar la medalla. Prueba a votar en alguna pregunta.

Comment: Pikoh, he intentado votar tanto preguntas como respuestas.

Comment: @jachguate ¿aún no ves la medalla "Vox pópili"?

Comment: @Jorge, no, desde anoche me sigue mostrando solamente 37 de 40 votos emitidos. Revisé mi actividad luego del primer comentario de Pikoh y efectivamente, puedo contar solamente 37 votos emitidos, pero ya no me deja votar ni en preguntas ni en respuestas.

Comment: En ese caso, me remito al post que enlaza @Jorgesys al meta en inglés, donde explica el sistema de límites que es bastante mas complejo de lo que yo pensaba...

Comment: Nótese que 10 de los votos deben ser a preguntas. Y luego está el caching

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Lista de todas las medallas con su descripción completa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2699/lista-de-todas-las-medallas-con-su-descripci%c3%b3n-completa) y [Máximo número de votos diarios. ¿Cómo llego a la medalla Vóx Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/525/83)

Comment: Gracias @fedorqui, no había caído en la cuenta y ahora veo que se ha explicado muy bien en ese post acá en meta, he marcado yo mismo la pregunta como duplicada para dejar la redirección hacia allá. Un saludo. :)

Answer (score -1):

Te comento que no es un bug, en realidad solo se permiten 40 votos por día.

Los votos permitidos ya sean a preguntas o respuestas son 40 en 24 horas.

Al tratar de emitir tu voto, cuando no se permitido te indicara las horas que faltan para que puedas votar nuevamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**De acuerdo a el problema que comentas, la obtención de medallas (o de sombreros) o de información relacionada a actividad del sitio no se realiza de forma automática, así que tienes que esperar unos minutos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[What are the limits on how I can cast, change, and retract votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes/5213#5213)

[Máximo número de votos diarios. ¿Cómo llego a la medalla Vóx Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/525/m%C3%A1ximo-n%C3%BAmero-de-votos-diarios-c%C3%B3mo-llego-a-la-medalla-v%C3%B3x-populi)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy consciente de eso. De hecho, anoche, lo dejé así, pero han pasado unas 9 horas desde eso y el contador sigue en 37 y sigue sin dejarme votar.

Comment: Ahora entiendo el límite, creo que valdría la pena traducir [la respuesta enlazada](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/149992) al español. No tengo tiempo para verificar ahora el cálculo, pero seguro es por eso que solamente pude emitir 37 en el día. Gracias por apuntarme en la dirección correcta.